# Do angular promises resolve in same order as they are sent?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, angular-promise

I have an array of promises of `$http.get`. I would like to know if these promises shall be resolved in the same order as they were pushed to array. Like, for example:

```
samplepromises.push($http.get(sampleurl, {responseType: 'blob'}));
...
...
$q.all(samplepromises).then(function(promisearr) {

});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. From [the documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#all):

> Returns a single promise that will be resolved with an array/hash of
>   values, each value corresponding to the promise at the same index/key
>   in the promises array/hash. If any of the promises is resolved with a
>   rejection, this resulting promise will be rejected with the same
>   rejection value